# Skeleton Animation -- How to flip a FTCCharacter?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

This is my very first question in Stack Overflow.

I am playing around with the skeletal animation with Cocos2d. By using TheDamArmada / Flash2Cocos2D library,I can init a FTCCharacter which is inherited from CCSprite. I try to flip the whole character by using `myRobot.flipX = YES`, but it is not working.

Any suggestion?

Here's an inline link to [Flash2Cocos2D](https://github.com/TheDamArmada/Flash2Cocos2D).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Cocos2D Source (CCSprite.h:121)

```
/** whether or not the sprite is flipped horizontally.
 It only flips the texture of the sprite, and not the texture of the sprite's children.
 Also, flipping the texture doesn't alter the anchorPoint.
 If you want to flip the anchorPoint too, and/or to flip the children too use:

    sprite.scaleX *= -1;
 */
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) BOOL flipX;
```

So it is expected that children of FTCCharacter is not flipped.
`myRobot.scaleX *= -1;` should work as suggested by Cocos2D.

Comment: It is always a good idea to explain what you think was the problem with the OP's code and how your solution fixes the issue :) You might want to edit your answer and update it to make it more relevant to the question.